# Extract Delimited Data in a string input

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert a string which is delimited by a ";"
Here are the possible inputs that i have

```
Possibility 1: <String>1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11</String>
Possibility 2: <String>1;2;3;4;5</String>
Possibility 3: <String>1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9</String>
Possibility 4: <String>1;2;3;4</String>
Possibility 5: <String>1;2;3;4;5;;;;;10;11</String>
```

Few points concerning the logic

Would like to have the above delimited strings mapped to individual
   fields like shown below.

Not concerned about the values in position 6
   and 7 and hence they are not seen in any of the outputs

Towards the
   end of the output is an element with name "combined" which is a
   concatenation of values received in string delimited by an "_"

Order of concatenation though is slightly different which is mentioned here
   1_2_3_4_5_8_11_9_10

If a value is not present in input string then it remains blank like 1__3_4_5__11__10

Output that i would like to see for each of above mentioned possibilities is

```
Possibility 1:

<A>1</A>
<B>2</B>
<C>3</C>
<D>4</D>
<E>5</E>
<F>8</F>
<G>9</G>
<H>10</H>
<I>11</I>
<Combined>1_2_3_4_5_8_11_9_10</Combined>

Possibility 2:
<A>1</A>
<B>2</B>
<C>3</C>
<D>4</D>
<E>5</E>
<F></F>
<G></G>
<H></H>
<I></I>
<Combined>1_2_3_4_5____</Combined> 

Possibility 3:
<A>1</A>
<B>2</B>
<C>3</C>
<D>4</D>
<E>5</E>
<F>8</F>
<G>9</G>
<H></H>
<I></I>
<Combined>1_2_3_4_5_8__9_</Combined> 

Possibility 4:
<A>1</A>
<B>2</B>
<C>3</C>
<D>4</D>
<E></E>
<F></F>
<G></G>
<H></H>
<I>11</I>
<Combined>1_2_3_4_____</Combined> 

Possibility 5:
<A>1</A>
<B>2</B>
<C>3</C>
<D>4</D>
<E>5</E>
<F></F>
<G></G>
<H>10</H>
<I>11</I>
<Combined>1_2_3_4_5__11__10</Combined>
```

I am able to get the desired output if i assume that string is of fixed length with 11 delimited sets and this i was able to achieve by using substring before and after functions
However for possibilities like 2 3 4 provider is not always sending the empty delimiters and then my xsl doesnt seem to work.

Any help in this context please?

Comment: *"purposefully jumbled"* is not a good description of the logic that needs to be applied here. -- Also, which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? This could be much easier if the processor supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` or `str:split()` extension function.

Comment: What have you coded up to now?

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Thanks for your feedback. I made a correction to the question now which explains the logic . We are using Apache XALAN processor

Comment: @PierreFrançois : Here is a sample of the logic that we have implemented.Using statements as these we are successfully able to extract the values from delimited string and map them to individual values and also form the combined string as shown above. But the problem seem to be with assumption that i always have a fixed delimited string <xsl:value-of
       select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(string,';'),';'),';'),';'),';'),';'),';'),';'),';'),';')"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xalan, then this should work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="str:split(String, ';')" />
    <root>
        <A>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/>
        </A>
        <B>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[2]"/>
        </B>
        <C>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[3]"/>
        </C>
        <D>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[4]"/>
        </D>
        <E>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[5]"/>
        </E>
        <F>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[8]"/>
        </F>
        <G>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[9]"/>
        </G>
        <H>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[10]"/>
        </H>
        <I>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[11]"/>
        </I>
        <Combined>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[2]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[3]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[4]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[5]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[8]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[11]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[9]"/>
            <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[10]"/>
        </Combined>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you that works!! Wasnt aware that there is a direct function which can be used. Have now checked the documentation , thanks for the quick help @michael.hor257k